# Python naming convention - namedtuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, naming-conventions, pep8, namedtuple

I am new to Python and I have been reading both the online documentation and (trying) to follow [PEP 0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to have a good Python code style.
I am curious about the code segment I found in the official Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#writing-a-tokenizer) while studying about the re library:

```
import collections

Token = collections.namedtuple('Token', ['typ', 'value', 'line', 'column'])
```

I cannot understand why the *`Token`* variable is named with a first letter capitalised; I have read through the PEP 0008 and there is no reference for it for what I have seen. Should it not be **`token`** instead or **`TOKEN`** if it was a constant (which for all I know it is not)?

Comment: Because it's a class - `namedtuple` is a class factory.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the code-segment you provided, `Token` is a [**named tuple**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), definitely not a constant. It does not follow other variable names naming style only to put emphasis on the fact that it is a **class factory function**. 
No warning will occur from an PEP 0008 style checker (like *PyCharm* for example) if you write it as *`token`* but I think it is not good practice since this way it does not distinguish it as a class factory name.

So, *namedtuples* fall under the [Class names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) in PEP 0008. Too bad is not stated more explicitly.
Besides the example you mentioned for [writing a tokenizer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#writing-a-tokenizer), this can also be seen in the [collections.namedtuple docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) examples:

```
Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
Point3D = namedtuple('Point3D', Point._fields + ('z',))
Book = namedtuple('Book', ['id', 'title', 'authors'])
```

Comment: Anti Haapala's answer beat me to it. Great answer.

Comment: Well your answer is better :d

Comment: @Yannis, worth including info from Class names link that Class names should normally use the CapWords convention, consequently named tuples

Answer (score 8):

The key here is [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). As the documentation says,

> `collections.namedtuple(typename, field_names, verbose=False, rename=False)`
>
> Returns a new `tuple` **subclass** named `typename`. The new subclass is used to create `tuple`-like objects that have fields accessible by attribute lookup as well as being indexable and iterable. Instances of the subclass also have a helpful docstring (with typename and field_names) and a helpful `__repr__()` method which lists the tuple contents in a `name=value` format.

There is no PEP 8 violation; `Token` is an user-defined class and its name is capitalized as it should.